Error Encountered During Plugin Profiling
I encountered an error while profiling a plugin step and making changes to a record. I got popup with error:

Exception Message: An unexpected error occurred from ISV code. (ErrorType = ClientError) Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute):  PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin: System.Security.SecurityException: The data contract type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault' cannot be serialized in partial trust because the property 'ExceptionRetriable' does not have a public getter.

When I enabled tracing in MS CRM I got some details in PluginTraceLog:

An unexpected error occurred from ISV code. (ErrorType = ClientError)  PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

The issue began several months ago.
System administrators have confirmed that the problem is not due to any configuration on their end.
I searched online extensively but only found a potentially related post https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/db7097/request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-security-permissions-securitypermission. However, this post is outdated. A .NET configuration panel seems to be removed in Framework versions 4 and above.
I also tried using different versions of the PluginRegistrationTool without success.
Our environment uses:
Windows Server 2022,
Microsoft Dynamics CRM 9.1.0026.0023 (on-premise)
Has anyone encountered something similar and can give advice on how to fix it?

Does the ISV error pop up when you run the plugin without the profiler? I suspect it to be with your actual plugin code or plugin base.
can you perhaps share the plugin code on here? I have encountered this a few times and it's never the same reason but it is usually user code related.
My approach to fix this is to debug locally with unit tests and Xrm Fake Easy. I would recreate the data in the unit test and debug it from there if you can't get the profiler to work. Also try the pac cli and once install run the plugin registration tool from there with the following command:
pac tool prt

If you can share some code it would help me so I can review and maybe try to replicate the issue on my end.

Hello! No, without profiling step all working well. Error appearing only when profiling on a step is active. So I'm sure the problem is not in the plugin code.

Are you packaging as an assembly or package? Also are you running the latest plugin registration tool using pac tool prt?

@AlexSecond I would say that tracing would be your best bet. Add tracing steps in your code and see where it fails or if it does. Then look in the Plugin Trace Log to debug. Also wrap your code in a try-catch and log/trace the exception. Hopefully when you profile the plugin it will log the issue. The only other thing I can think of is version of the PRT is outdated? Also if you are packaging as nuget package, profiler doesnt work
